# Nuxt 3 ignores TypeScript errors when saving the code

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem. When there is a TypeScript error in the code, there is an error in the IDE, but I anyways can save it and run in the browser. Is it okay?

Here is the code:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const a = ref<string>(5);
</script>
```

I tried export default and export default defineComponent(), but it didn't help.

Here is the screenshoot of my IDE
[image: You can see the error, but Nuxt.js just updates without any problem.]

Comment: typescript doesn't run in the browser, it's always transpiled to javascript beforehand, that's why you can break typescript specific rules and still run your code ok.  it's up to you as a developer whether you feel this is an ok practice, though most would say it's bad practice to follow.

Comment: @yoduh, yes, i mean when i save the code, it compiles to JS without giving any errors in the terminal. If i do this with React or just Vue 3, it would give an error, but Nuxt is not doing it, it's working with errors without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the nuxt 3 documentation [typescript/type-checking](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript#type-checking):

> By default, Nuxt doesn't check types when you run nuxi dev or nuxi build, for performance reasons.

If you want to enable it, you need to:

- install `vue-tsc` and `typescript` as `devDependencies`
- add this in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
typescript: {
  typeCheck: true,
}
```